# Query to convert the decimal column value to million or thousands

Tags: sql-server

I am running a select query on a database and want below formatting on Price(decimal) column

If the count is greater than million say 4,850,304.00, I want the query to return 4.85M.
If the count is greater than 1000 but less than a million say 75335.00 I want the query to return '75.3k'.
If the count is less than 1000 then the query should return actual count

I am trying below Query

```
Select Id, Product,format(Price, '$0','M') from Product table
```

Answer (score 0):

This "smells" bad. In almost all cases you would want the query to return a number (integer) and then have the front end format the output for display.

In order to do this you have to return a string which means the caller can't understand the number -- you could also include a formatted and unformatted column.  To get the formatted column you can use the case statement, I did not bother with the implementation details of each case:

```
CASE 
  WHEN price < 1000 THEN -- format here for less than 1000
  WHEN price < 1000000 THEN -- format here for 1K to < 1M
  ELSE -- format here for greater than 1M
END CASE as PRICE_FORMATTED
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you may try the following statement:

```
SELECT 
  Id, 
  Product, 
  Price,
  CASE 
     WHEN Price < 1000 THEN FORMAT(Price, '#0.00')
     WHEN 1000 <= Price AND Price < 1000000 THEN FORMAT(ROUND(Price / 1000.0, 2), '#0.00K')
     WHEN 1000000 <= Price THEN FORMAT(ROUND(Price / 1000000.0, 2), '#0.00M')
  END AS FormattedPrice
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 'Product1', 4850304.00),
   (2, 'Product2', 75335.00),
   (3, 'Product3', 335.10)
) Product (Id, Product, Price)
```

Result:

```
Id  Product        Price    FormattedPrice
1   Product1  4850304.00    4.85M
2   Product2    75335.00    75.34K
3   Product3      335.10    335.10
```

Comment: if you switch the 2nd and 3rd case then you only need to check one bound -- see my answer

Comment: You are right, @Hogan. I'm focused on the formatting, so I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In completing Zhorov answer , you can create a function for Format prices and use that in your queries.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FORMATPRICE(@price decimal)
RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)
    AS BEGIN
        RETURN
         CASE  
            WHEN @price < 1000 THEN FORMAT(@price, '#0.00')
            WHEN 1000 <= @price AND @price < 1000000 THEN FORMAT(ROUND(@price / 1000.0, 2), '#0.00K')
            WHEN 1000000 <= @price THEN FORMAT(ROUND(@price / 1000000.0, 2), '#0.00M')
           END
    END
```

And in queries :

```
select dbo.FORMATPRICE(4850304.00),dbo.FORMATPRICE(75335.00)
```

Comment: functions are really slow and a really bad idea.